# Kubernetes Deployments - Difference between status replicas and spec replicas

Tags: kubernetes

Need to know the difference between kube_deployment_status_replicas and kube_deployment_spec_replicas metric in kubernetes deployments

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell the difference is actual state vs desired state.

`kube_deployment_status_replicas`  means the number of replicas per deployment. This is the value of `Status.Replicas`.

From the [API docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#deploymentstatus-v1-apps).

> Total number of non-terminated pods targeted by this deployment (their
>   labels match the selector).

`kube_deployment_spec_replicas` means number of desired pods for a deployment. This is the value of `Spec.Replicas`

From the [API docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#deploymentspec-v1-apps).

> Number of desired pods. This is a pointer to distinguish between
>   explicit zero and not specified. Defaults to 1.